# Where is Ruby/Rails/Hobo dryml <if> documentation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, hobo

I'm trying to port a ruby/rails/hobo app. How do I use the "if" tag in dryml?

```
  <if:dist_image>
     <div>
       <a href="#{image.url}">
         <img src="#{image.url :thumbnail}" title="Click to enlarge"/>
       </a>
     </div>
  </if>
```

dist_image may be an object (containing an image), or it may be nil. Nothing seems to work. Also I can't find any documentation for conditional operators in dryml.

I get the error:

```
"undefined method `url' for "<img alt=\"Assets\" src=\"/assets/\">":ActionView::OutputBuffer"
```

Update: Hi everyone, thanks for your suggestions.. I tried all of the following:

```
  <if test="&dist_image">
  <if test="&dist_image.blank?">
  <if test="dist_image.blank?">
  <if test="dist_image">
```

all of them produce the same error. :( I followed the syntax in the documentation but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is `<%= image_tag image.url(:thumbnail), :title=>"Click to enlarge" %>` not working?

Comment: See [DRYML Guide: Conditionals](http://cookbook.hobocentral.net/manual/dryml-guide#conditionals__if_and_unless), found in 2 clicks via `dryml markup`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't with your if statement, it's with #{image.url}.   You probably want #{this.image.url} or #{this.url} or something.   `<if:dist_image>` sets the context to `this.dist_image`, so it does the equivalent of `this = this.dist_image`.

Calling it the way you do means that you're calling a helper called 'image' instead of getting the image attribute from your object.

BTW, you probably don't need to look up the documentation for `<if>`, what you probably need is the documentation for the DRYML context, which is also in the DRYML guide.